JWT Token Not Accessible in PHP Server-Side Function in WordPress for External API Request
I'm working on a WordPress project where I need to capture form data and send it to an external API. I'm using a JWT token to authenticate this request, but I can't seem to retrieve the token in my PHP function. Here’s the setup and the steps I’ve taken:
Frontend Setup:
The frontend sends an authentication request, and upon successful login, I set a JWT token in a cookie:
res.cookie("Token", jwtToken, {
  path: "/",
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  sameSite: "None",
  domain: "3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms"
});

I'm using wpforms_process_complete in WordPress to capture form submission data and send it to an external API. Here’s my PHP function:
function capture_all_form_data_as_json($fields, $entry, $form_data) {
    $form_data_json = [];
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (isset($field['name']) && isset($field['value'])) {
            $form_data_json[$field['name']] = $field['value'];
        }
    }
    
    $jwt_token = isset($_COOKIE['Token']) ? $_COOKIE['Token'] : null;
    error_log('JWT Token: ' . ($jwt_token ? 'found' : 'not found'));
    
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ];
    if ($jwt_token) {
        $headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' . $jwt_token;
    } else {
        error_log('Warning: JWT Token not found in cookies.');
    }
    
    $response = wp_remote_post('https://external-api.com/receive-data', [
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'body'      => json_encode($form_data_json),
        'headers'   => $headers,
    ]);
    
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        error_log('Error: ' . $response->get_error_message());
    }
}
add_action('wpforms_process_complete', 'capture_all_form_data_as_json', 10, 3);

Even though the JWT token should be set in cookies, my function logs that the JWT token is not found in $_COOKIE.
I’ve verified that the cookie is indeed present in the browser and has the correct domain and path settings, but it’s not accessible within PHP.

In the backend when I try to output the key only for testing purposes is comes out as:

I'm using Elementor Wordpress frontend and Nodejs Express backend. The hook function is in functions.php of my theme. It successfully sends the form data but never finds the token, I also tried error_log:ing out the headers and the token doesn't exist there either.

Please clarify what gets send from where to where here, exactly. Which of the two domains we're seeing in your screenshot, is your "frontend domain", that you requested the page from? Is this a normal form submission, or is it AJAX/fetch? And if the latter, is the request cross-origin, or not?

Yes, so the the frontend is talopakettiin.fi which is a wordpress website. And the backend is on a different domain at the moment for production, i forwarded a port to the public from the VScode ports feature. the current network tab im showing is the frontend's cookies, I attempt to send back the form data, which is a regular form submission from WPforms, the hook captures it and send it using the php function above. So the request is cross-origin but the origin is allowed in my index.js file.

"which is a regular form submission from WPforms" - does that mean it is a normal form submission (no AJAX/fetch involved), or is the AJAX option enabled in the WPForms settings?

"I'm using Elementor Wordpress frontend and Nodejs Express backend" - at which point does Nodejs Express get involved, and how? The WPForms submission is processed by Wordpress, PHP code - which domain name is that part actually happening "under" now, does that request go to talopakettiin.fi, or 3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms?

The request goes to 3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms, which is the backend on which NodeJs runs. The frontend is on talopakettiin.fi. I open the functions.php which automatically runs when the page is opened. I fetch the headers using an html script plugged into the page, that stored to the cookie in the cookies tab, after that the submission hook in functions.php send the form data and the cookie back to the backend. I hope that clarifies.

If the request is send to your NodeJS backend, then how exactly does the PHP code get executed? "I open the functions.php" - so your NodeJS somehow passes this request on to the PHP script, is that what you are saying? How exactly then?

In wordpress every website has a php file called functions.php that can execute various functions, it makes it easier to make requests. In here I have a form on my page, when i submit the hook in the php function catches it. After that it should send it back to the server with the cookie intact, but it gets lost. I dont quite understand why the cookie here gets lost. And i also don't understand how to keep the cookie accessible on the server side.

Yes, I am familiar with how WP works. But your actual setup here, is still unclear to me. How NodeJS comes into play, how that is even relevant to the problem - I can't currently see it. "The request goes to 3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms, which is the backend on which NodeJs runs." - if the request goes to NodeJS, then how is the WordPress PHP code getting invoked? Or is your WP PHP code running under that hostname as well - and we are talking about different ports for WP and NodeJS?

The function in functions.php is invoked after i submit a form, it triggers with a wp-submission-hook. .the php function posts the data to "/forms/receive-form-data", there is a function in the backend that handles the data and should recieves the cookie with the header. It doesn't find it, hence when i attempt to log it in the backend as seem above, it comes back as undefined. Also in the error_logs the token doesn't exist, but i can view it in the Application tab as a cookie. I hope this is clear enough. I haven't found any solutions to my problem.

"the php function posts the data to /forms/receive-form-data" - which PHP function are you talking about now? The one you have shown us above, makes an external API request to https://external-api.com/receive-data.

function capture_all_form_data_as_json() send the data to https://3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms//forms/receive-form-data. that is the external-api i was talking about. Is it okay if you could help in private message if you are good with cookies?

Right, so your request from the frontend shown under talopakettiin.fi, is going to the WP backend, which is also hosted under talopakettiin.fi - is that correct? Well then you can't expect the client to send a cookie for a totally different domain with that request. For the browser to send a cookie that was set for 3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms, the request would have to go to 3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms as well.

Okay, so i have the backend under https://3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms/ which is where the (temporary) backend is, i need to have both the backend and frontend under the same domain (talopakettiin.fi) for the cookie to be found?

Basically, yes. Cookies are only accepted from the "rightful" setter, and only send back to the "rightful" recipient. The browser only accepted the cookie that was set for 3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms to begin with here, because that request was made to 3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms. And because it is set for 3vbp2t1s-8000.euw.devtunnels.ms, it will also only be send back with requests going to that same host name (or subdomains thereof.) But it will not be send with a request to talopakettiin.fi.

Okay thanks a lot, sorry if my explanation was confusing. I will temporarily for production store it in the local storage, when i deploy the backend to api.talopakettiin.fi this issue should not presist, correct?

"when i deploy the backend to api.talopakettiin.fi this issue should not presist, correct?" - only if your form submission was send there as well, it will not work if that goes to talopakettiin.fi or www.talopakettiin.fi instead.  If your client-side request to fetch the token goes to api.talopakettiin.fi, the response will only be able to set a cookie that is valid for api.talopakettiin.fi, and subdomains thereof. It won't be able to set a cookie that is valid for talopakettiin.fi - you can't go "further up" in the hierarchy, only down.

Yes, but i can set the path to "/" therefore it includes all subdomains as well correct?

No. Domain is domain, and path is path. The path component of a URL is the part after the host name, up to the start of the query string. If you set a cookie with domain example.com and path /, then that cookie will be send back with all requests for anything below example.com, and any arbitrary subdomain like xyz.example.com as well. [...]

[...] But if you set the path to /foobar/, then the cookie will only be send back with requests to  example.com/foobar/ and below (such as example.com/foobar/something), and again also including subdomains, but not for example.com/abc/ or anything below, and not for xyz.example.com/abc/ or anything below either.

Can you please check a new problem of mine that has come up? I describe it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79204487/unable-to-access-cookie-in-domain-that-is-set-in-subdomain
